# Giving a downvote decreased my reputation

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I asked a question on Stack Overflow. A guy responded to my question and gave an unrelated answer, without reading the question properly. Plus there was no explanation to the answer, **just code**. I gave that answer a downvote, but then I was also charged '-1' reputation.

I tried searching on this site to know the reason. One thing I found that you are charged for every downvote. So I am wondering, does Stack Overflow encourage to not downvote a poorly written wrong answer?

Comment: MSE: [If downvoting is so important, why does it cost reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62130/if-downvoting-is-so-important-why-does-it-cost-reputation)

Comment: @AzizShaikh ah! Sorry for that. I searched and didn't find it.

Comment: @MangatRai no worries. Sometimes it takes a couple of attempts (using different search terms) to find a duplicate.

Comment: Closing my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really think so, this does however force you to think twice before you downvote something, is it really worth it?

Also people don't just randomly downvote every answer on the site without any penalty.